# Can you make IntelliJ display relative paths in the console?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

Can I make this

```
at tryRunOrWebpackError (/home/barakiva/Development/Projects/Interviews/SockChat/sock-chat-client/node_modules/webpack/lib/HookWebpackError.js:88:9)
at __webpack_require_module__ (/home/barakiva/Development/Projects/Interviews/SockChat/sock-chat-client/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:5051:12)
```

look like this?

```
 at tryRunOrWebpackError (~sock-chat-client/node_modules/webpack/lib/HookWebpackError.js:88:9)
 at __webpack_require_module__ (~sock-chat-client/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:5051:12)
```

Basically, to make the console more readable, I'd love to find a way to truncate redundancies, which for me are mostly paths.

Comment: It's not about *making console* more readable; it's what is printed, via output stream, into the console. What you're asking for is to make console strip off (substring) the messages, which console is not designed for to do.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri sorry. Then I guess I am asking for the console to strip off redundancies given to it via stdout. Is that possible?

Comment: Some code prints something into the console, right? so, it's either 1) you control what's sent into the output (that finally arrives into the console), and if it's not your code that prints the string (let's say it's a library API call, and not you throwing exception) into console, you do not have a control what's printed; 2) you program console to receive full data, but substring it, which I think is less likely to be possible.